# iOS 7 click / touch events causing swiper resize

Tags: jquery, ios7, click, swiper.js, touchstart

I've been trying to debug this issue on iOS 7 and it's driving me mad. I use the iDangerous Swiper (http://www.idangero.us/swiper/get-started/). With clickable buttons in the slide to advance to the next slide. There is also an AJAX submit on that button click. I've been trying to use the touchstart event to make the clicking more reliable on mobile. Which has been successful, but on the iphone 6 (iOS 7) the swiper flickers / resizes before the first slide moves. On all other browsers I've tested it is fine.

To debug I tried delaying all the events that fire by a few seconds to see which one is causing it by using setTimeout. When I delay the events the flicker / resize doesn't happen.

I'm out of ideas about what could be causing this or how to debug it.

The jquery triggers are as follows:

```
var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");

// make click more reliable on mobile

$(".swiper-slide fieldset.rating > label").bind(clickHandler, function(e) {

  setTimeout(function() {

   $(this).prev('input').click()
            .siblings('input').attr('checked',false)
            .end()
            .attr('checked', true);
    return false;
  }, 0); // end timeout
});


// Advance on click
//$('.swiper-slide input:radio[name^="number"]:not(.other_text)').on('click', function(e){
$('.swiper-slide input:radio[name^="number"],a.other_done').on('click', function(e){
  //$(this).next('label').html('<i class="ss-icon1 i-smile1satsum-survey"></i>');
  setTimeout(function () {
    //alert('about to trigger move');
    mySwiper.swipeNext();
  }, 200);

});

$(document).on('change', 'fieldset.rating', function (event) {
setTimeout(function () {
    //alert('about to post data');
    console.log('posting data');
    val = $(this).children('input:checked').val();
    name  = $(this).children('input:checked').attr('name');
    base_name  = name.split("[data]")[0];
    id_name = base_name + "[id]";
    id = $('input[name="' + id_name + '"]').val();

if (id > 0) {
   json_string = "{ \"" + name + "\": \"" + val + "\", \"" + id_name + "\": \"" + id + "\" }";
} else {
   json_string = "{ \"" + name + "\": \"" + val + "\" }";
};
    json_object = JSON.parse(json_string);
url = $(location).attr('href');
number_url = url.split("/play")[0];

// Change thankyou text
if (base_name == "number[recom]") {
       if (val == 5) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_p').addClass("ty_active");
   } else if (val == 4) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_n').addClass("ty_active");
       } else if (val < 4) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_d').addClass("ty_active");
       }
}



$.ajax({
type: "PUT",
url: number_url,
dataType: "json",
data: json_object
//})
//.done(function( msg ) {
//alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

  },400); // end settimeout
});
```

I've also tried the "cursor:pointer" fix, with no luck. Someone please give me some ideas!

Comment: I believe this was the offending piece of code:                                        `// Change thankyou text
if (base_name == "number[recom]") {
       if (val == 5) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_p').addClass("ty_active");
   } else if (val == 4) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_n').addClass("ty_active");
       } else if (val < 4) {
          $('.custom_thankyou').removeClass("ty_active");
          $('#custom_thankyou_d').addClass("ty_active");
       }
}`

Comment: So I believe the issue is that I am dynamically changing the content which is upsetting iOS. I do need to change the content though, so the question is how do that.

Comment: i have almost same issue here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283736/swiper-pagination-and-ios-resize-issues
hope anyone can help me.